# Saving custom fields to a custom taxonomy

Tags: posts, custom-taxonomy, post-meta, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to create a custom field for a custom taxonomy.  update_post_meta works great with posts.  Taxonomies are not posts so this won't work.

```
<?php update_post_meta($post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $prev_value); ?>
```

How would I save a custom field within a custom taxonomy?  Other solutions include the options_table (bad!) or creating a custom table (cumbersome).  Is there another, canned solution or function to help with this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
update_metadata()
```

great post on [Adding Custom Fields to Taxonomy](http://shibashake.com/wordpress-theme/add-term-or-taxonomy-meta-data).

The solution outlined does require creating an additional database table but it does the job perfectly.

Comment: Adding another table to store meta data is not the best way - not recommended.

Comment: Why?  Is there a better solution?  We are talking about saving metadata for custom fields on a custom post type.  Couldn't find anything canned that fits.  What is better?  Still learning so thanks.

Comment: n/p. You can use the `description` columns content inside the `term_taxonomy` table. There you simply save a `JSON` encoded array.

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't what you're looking for the [wp_set_object_terms](http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies#Using_that_taxonomy) function?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. But +1, as it's often overseen.

Answer (score -1):

First you need to add the fields you wish to attach to that taxonomy...
There are several solution but a gr8 member of wordpress.stackexchange.com
called @bainternet released the best solution i have seen yet for:

- adding fields to your taxonomies & Saving them.

**You should have a look:**
[wordpress taxonomies extra fields the easy way](http://en.bainternet.info/2012/wordpress-taxonomies-extra-fields-the-easy-way)

it helped solved a recent project.
hope this answers your need...

Best of luck
sagive

Comment: This solution saves _every_ set of meta data as entry in the `options` table. Not a nice solution and will clutter a table, that holds most of the autoloaded options, so it will slow down every request over the time.